# AngularJS ng-style with ng-model scope variable

Tags: css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a website to let users design their own mobile app. One side of the website has a form that the user fills out, and the other side has a live preview of the app based off of the form data. This is how it is set up:

Controller:

```
$scope.primaryColor = "#325490";
```

Form Input:

```
<!-- Primary Color -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="primaryColor" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Primary:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.primaryColor">
    </div>
</div>
```

Live Preview:

```
<div class="mockView" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{$parent.backgroundFile}})', 'background-color':'{{$parent.primaryColor}}'}">
```

I have to use $parent because I am using ng-include on my index page to include the form.htm and preview.htm files. I have tested the form and I know it is changing all of the scope variables that I have, but the previewer is not changing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove {{}} and '' and it should work, like this:

`<div class="mockView" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{$parent.backgroundFile}})', 'background-color': $parent.primaryColor }">`